# Converting countrycode to countryname using xslt

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

I am trying to get the value of the CountryName based from the position of the CountryCode. For example in XML File,

```
<CountryCode>USA</CountryCode>
```

**XSLT Code:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
exclude-result-prefixes="xs">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="no"/>
<xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="Party">
    <xsl:copy-of select="node()|@*"/>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="CountryCode">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:variable name="CountryCode" select="upper-case(.)=('HK','USA','SG')"/> // list of country codes
        <xsl:variable name="CountryName" as="element()*"> // list of countryname
            <Name>HongKong</Name>
            <Name>United States of America</Name>
            <Name>Singapore</Name>
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:value-of select="$CountryName[($CountryCode)]"/> // get the position or index of the variable countryname to variable countrycode
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

But, I am getting all the value of CountryName. Like this,

```
<CountryCode>Philippines United States of America Singapore</CountryCode>
```

instead of `<CountryCode>United States of America</CountryCode>`

Is there something missing in my code? or I am doing it in a wrong way?

Thanks in advance.

**XSLT2.0**

Answer (score 2):

If your country codes are ISO 3166 codes, and if you can use an XSLT 3.0 processor, then you could simply do

```
<xsl:template match="CountryCode">
  <xsl:copy>{json-doc('http://country.io/names.json')(.)}</xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

If you're not using ISO 3166 codes, or if you're not using XSLT 3.0, then perhaps you can be persuaded to change...

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using XSLT 2.0, you can use the `index-of` function to get the index of `CountryCode` from `$CountryCode` variable and then use the value of the index to get the `CountryName` from `$CountryName`.

Please try modifying the template matching `<CountryCode>` as below.

```
<xsl:template match="CountryCode">
    <!-- Store input in a variable -->
    <xsl:variable name="InputCode" select="." />
    <xsl:copy>
        <!-- Removed the upper-case function and retained the sequence -->
        <xsl:variable name="CountryCode" select="('HK','USA','SG')"/>

        <xsl:variable name="CountryName" as="element()*">
            <Name>HongKong</Name>
            <Name>United States of America</Name>
            <Name>Singapore</Name>
        </xsl:variable>

        <!-- Added the index-of function to get the index of the input country
             code from the sequence and then extract the country name from the
             other sequence -->
        <xsl:value-of select="$CountryName[index-of($CountryCode, upper-case($InputCode))]"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

For input

```
<CountryCode>USA</CountryCode>
```

the above template will give an output as

```
<CountryCode>United States of America</CountryCode>
```